# Simple Command to robot fails

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem writing a simple node that publishes messages of a type called JointVelocity which has 2 objects  called velocity of the type `JointQuantity` and header of the type `Header.` When I run the following code I get the message:

```
TypeError: unbound method serialize() must be called with JointVelocity instance as first agrugment (got  String0 instance instead)
```

Thanks for your help!
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from iiwa_msgs.msg import JointVelocity


def talker():
    velPub = rospy.Publisher('iiwa/command/JointVelocity',JointVelocity ,queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('Velocity_Transmitter', anonymous =False)
    
    rate = rospy.Rate(0.5) # 10hz
    x = 0
    rospy.loginfo("Talker gestartet")
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    
        rospy.loginfo(str(x))
    
    
        x = x + 1
    
        vel = JointVelocity
    
    
        vel.velocity = [Float32(0.1),Float32(0.2),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1)]
    
        vel.header= Header()
        vel.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        vel.header.frame_id = ''
        vel.header.seq=1
        rospy.loginfo(vel.velocity[1])
        rospy.loginfo("Velocity will be transmitted")
        velPub.publish(vel)
        rospy.loginfo("Velocity has been transmitted")
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
      talker()
  #velocity_talker()
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277115/simple-command-to-robot-fails/) by [Smoerebroed](https://answers.ros.org/users/32836/smoerebroed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-01**:
What's the full error? Many times there's an indication to what line is giving you problems. Also, is this all of your code? I just ran it and got no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have:

```
vel = JointVelocity
vel.velocity = [Float32(0.1),Float32(0.2),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1),Float32(0.1)]
```

Where you try to feet the velocity values in the JointVelocity class itself. What you want is to create an instance first (Note the braces):

```
vel = JointVelocity()
vel.velocity = [...]
```

Also you usually don't need to cast to Float32, so you can simply write

```
vel.velocity = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1